# How to set a mpreal parameter inside a Fortran module

Tags: module, fortran

I'd really like to be able to define some parameters in a Fortran module, so so that they are accessible for the main program and all its subroutines.

The problem is that even when I try to declare them in the program body, such as:

```
type (mp_real), parameter :: p1   = 1.98342E+5 !(or say 1.1d0)
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Can't convert REAL(4) to TYPE(mp_real) at (1)

Basically I have no problem setting the value of the parameter in the body of the program, but if I try to do it inside the variable declaration area, `gfortran` is not happy. And this stops me from defining them in a module. 
Is there a way to set the value of the parameters inside a module with `mpreal` or I should rework the whole program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you are using the [mpfun](http://www.netlib.org/mpfun/) library, which defines a type `mp_real` exactly how you use it.

Then, they overload the assignment operator to be able to convert types. This operator is not available at compile time which results in the error you get.

Here is an example to illustrate this:

```
module test_mod

  type my_type
    integer :: val
  end type

  interface assignment (=)
    module procedure my_assign
  end interface

contains

  subroutine my_assign( t, v )
    type(my_type),intent(out) :: t
    integer, intent(in)       :: v
  end subroutine
end module

program test
  use test_mod

  type(my_type),parameter :: t = 1
end program
```

To my knowledge, it is not possible to use derived types in the manner you suggest. You could, however, store `p1` as a real, and use an initializing subroutine...

Comment: Yes, I also thought this might be the problem, because when I use mpreal(1.1d0) in the parameter declaration, it tells me "Error: Function 'mpreal' in initialization expression at (1) must be an intrinsic function
"
Thank you for your reply. Then I'll have to rework the code.